# On approximations and reductions

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions

This may be a naive question but I am a bit clueless. I was under the opinion that given two NP complete problems, $P1$ and $P2$, if $P2 \in APX$ and $P1 \notin APX$, then we cannot have a direct reduction $P2\leq P1$ but we can have a reduction $P1\leq P2$.

In this paper on page 165 http://www.lancaster.ac.uk/staff/letchfoa/articles/cut-projection.pdf, there is a reduction $MAXCUT \leq STABLESET$. That is, given an instance of *STABLESET*, I can find an instance of *MAXCUT*. Why cant I use the approximate solution for *MAXCUT* to find an approximate solution to *STABLESET*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, a reduction need not preserve approximations. For more details, see [my answer on cstheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/18937/on-apx-problems/18939#18939) to a similar question.

Comment: ah, i wanted to give the vertex-cover VS independent-set example, but Yuval is just too quick.